# how to create a new xlsx file using openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

Does anybody knows how to create a new xlsx file using openpyxl in python?

```
filepath = "/home/ubun/Desktop/stocksinfo/yyy.xlsx"
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filepath)
ws = wb.get_active_sheet()
```

What do I need to add?

Comment: What do you really want? You want to create a new xlsx file?

Comment: create a non existing xlsx file.

Answer (score 54):

I'm sorry my head is turning around. :)
This solves the problem

```
filepath = "/home/ubun/Desktop/stocksinfo/test101.xlsx"
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()

wb.save(filepath)
```

This will create a new file.

[Documentation site](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) contains quickstart on front page.

Comment: I'm doing this now, but openpyxl.Workbook() throws error. Simply wb = Workbook()  works when already imported with from openpyxl import Workbook

Answer (score 17):

Install and Import openpyxl

```
import openpyxl
```

Create new workbook

```
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
```

Get SHEET name

```
Sheet_name = wb.sheetnames
```

Save created workbook at same path where .py file exist

```
wb.save(filename='Test.xlsx')
```

Comment: Please follow the guidelines on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer since in the current form, your answer looks hastily written.

Answer (score 4):

This is covered in the documentation: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#saving-to-a-file

`wb.save(…)`

Comment: sir I'm trying to create a non existing file. not modify a existing file

Comment: So what? Just use the name for your new file.